# C++98: iterator_traits::value_type seems to be returning a pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++98

I come here as a last resort - I am absolutely out of ideas now.

I am modifying some function templates from a legacy project taking vectors as parameters so that they follow the STL paradigm by taking iterators instead.

My problem arises when I need to figure out the return type from the iterators. With this purpose, I have implemented the following template (now stripped to its bare minimum in my efforts to find a bug).

```
template<class InputIterator>
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type
foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type T;

    T out = T();

    return out;
}
```

This is then called as:

```
std::vector<float> test (10);

float value = foo(test.begin(), test.end());
```

which does not compile with:

> error 2440: cannot convert from 'float *' to 'float'.

As far as I understand, `iterator_traits::value_type` should return a value type, not a pointer type.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening or what could I be missing? Unfortunately, this project is C++98 so no default template parameters, `decltype`, `auto` or the like.

Comment: Clean build with  `g++ 5.1.0` and `-std=c++98`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either.